# My computer has crashed after I tried to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade

I was invited to upgrade by Ubuntu to 20.04 LTS. The upgrade started OK but when it got to about 80% it crashed. I was unable to recover it and when I restarted my computer all I got was flashing files of the upgrade down the left side of my screen. I cannot do anything with my computer now so can you advise me what to do to regain control. Thank you

Comment: You'll need a USB (or DVD) and the 20.04 .iso. *Write* the image to either medium, reboot, pick your USB drive to boot to (it's often F12 during the boot process, but check what your computer needs to boot from USB or DVD), and then you can backup your data and do a clean installation of 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

In general when the system fails during the upgrade, there is little chance for recovery. In my suggestion you have to make a clean installation of the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your swift reply to my problem. I would like reload 20.04 unfortunately my computer will not respond to anything. When I turn it on all I get is flashing files from 20.04 down one side of my screen. Sorry to be so thick about this but I would load any system (even microsoft) if I could just get my computer to respond after I switch it on. Thanks anyway.